# Deploying Ghost One-Click droplet on Digital Ocean: Exit code 1 when verifying domain

Tags: digital-ocean, netlify, ghost-blog

I'm trying to follow along with [DigitalOceans intructions on creating a one-click droplet](https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/ghost) in order to set up a ghost cms for my website.

I set up my website on Netlify, and had Netlify manage the dns. When Netlify manages the dns it looks like it automatically sets up ssl on Netlify.
The domain registrar is Namecheap.

When I ssh to my droplet I get the output below and visiting `https://example.com/ghost/` gives a 404 error, but I can still visit `https://example.com`

```
~ % ssh root@111.111.1.11
The authenticity of host '111.111.1.11 (111.111.1.11)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA111:aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '111.111.1.11' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@111.111.1.11's password: 

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring DigitalOcean 1-Click Ghost installation.

Please wait a minute while your 1-Click is configured. 

Once complete, you are encouraged to run mysql_secure_installation to ready
your server for production. Passwords have been saved to:

    root/.digitalocean_password

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Ensuring Ghost-CLI is up-to-date...
+ sudo npm i -g ghost-cli@latest
/usr/bin/ghost -> /usr/lib/node_modules/ghost-cli/bin/ghost
+ ghost-cli@1.13.1
added 59 packages from 29 contributors, removed 11 packages and updated 48 packages in 16.313s

Ghost will prompt you for two details:

1. Your domain
 - Add an A Record -> 111.111.1.11 & ensure the DNS has fully propagated
 - Or alternatively enter http://111.111.1.11
2. Your email address (only used for SSL)

Press enter when you're ready to get started!


+ sudo chown -R ghost-mgr:ghost-mgr /home/ghost-mgr/.config
✔ Checking system Node.js version
✔ Checking logged in user
✔ Checking current folder permissions
✔ Checking operating system compatibility
✔ Checking for a MySQL installation
✔ Checking memory availability
✔ Checking for latest Ghost version
✔ Setting up install directory
✔ Downloading and installing Ghost v3.13.4
✔ Finishing install process
? Enter your blog URL: https://example.com
✔ Configuring Ghost
✔ Setting up instance
+ sudo useradd --system --user-group ghost
+ sudo chown -R ghost:ghost /var/www/ghost/content
✔ Setting up "ghost" system user
ℹ Setting up "ghost" mysql user [skipped]
✔ Creating nginx config file at /var/www/ghost/system/files/example.com.conf
+ sudo ln -sf /var/www/ghost/system/files/example.com.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf
+ sudo ln -sf /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com.conf
+ sudo nginx -s reload
✔ Setting up Nginx
? Enter your email (For SSL Certificate) myemail@outlook.com
+ sudo mkdir -p /etc/letsencrypt
+ sudo ./acme.sh --install --home /etc/letsencrypt
+ sudo /etc/letsencrypt/acme.sh --issue --home /etc/letsencrypt --domain example.com --webroot /var/www/ghost/system/nginx-root --reloadcmd "nginx -s reload" --accountemail myemail@outlook.com
✖ Setting up SSL
✔ Creating systemd service file at /var/www/ghost/system/files/ghost_example-com.service
+ sudo ln -sf /var/www/ghost/system/files/ghost_example-com.service /lib/systemd/system/ghost_example-com.service
+ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
✔ Setting up Systemd
+ sudo systemctl is-active ghost_example-com
+ sudo systemctl start ghost_example-com
+ sudo systemctl is-enabled ghost_example-com
+ sudo systemctl enable ghost_example-com --quiet
✔ Starting Ghost
One or more errors occurred.

1) ProcessError

Message: Command failed: /bin/sh -c sudo -S -p '#node-sudo-passwd#'  /etc/letsencrypt/acme.sh --issue --home /etc/letsencrypt --domain example.com --webroot /var/www/ghost/system/nginx-root --reloadcmd "nginx -s reload" --accountemail myemail@outlook.com
[Tue Apr 21 18:30:16 UTC 2020] example.com:Verify error:Invalid response from https://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/vsRL-FT-yUeK0ntPgkXjl2-4vcYw8FV213estE4b1as [206.189.73.52]: 
[Tue Apr 21 18:30:16 UTC 2020] Please add '--debug' or '--log' to check more details.
[Tue Apr 21 18:30:16 UTC 2020] See: https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh/wiki/How-to-debug-acme.sh

[Tue Apr 21 18:30:11 UTC 2020] Create account key ok.
[Tue Apr 21 18:30:11 UTC 2020] Registering account
[Tue Apr 21 18:30:12 UTC 2020] Registered
[Tue Apr 21 18:30:12 UTC 2020] ACCOUNT_THUMBPRINT='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
[Tue Apr 21 18:30:12 UTC 2020] Creating domain key
[Tue Apr 21 18:30:12 UTC 2020] The domain key is here: /etc/letsencrypt/example.com/example.com.key
[Tue Apr 21 18:30:12 UTC 2020] Single domain='example.com'
[Tue Apr 21 18:30:12 UTC 2020] Getting domain auth token for each domain
[Tue Apr 21 18:30:13 UTC 2020] Getting webroot for domain='example.com'
[Tue Apr 21 18:30:13 UTC 2020] Verifying: example.com

Exit code: 1


Debug Information:
    OS: Ubuntu, v18.04.3 LTS
    Node Version: v10.16.3
    Ghost Version: 3.13.4
    Ghost-CLI Version: 1.13.1
    Environment: production
    Command: 'ghost install --auto --db=mysql --dbhost=localhost --dbname=ghost_production --dbuser=ghost --dbpass=bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb --dir=/var/www/ghost --start'

Additional log info available in: /home/ghost-mgr/.ghost/logs/ghost-cli-debug-2020-04-21T18_30_42_032Z.log

Try running ghost doctor to check your system for known issues.

You can always refer to https://ghost.org/docs/api/ghost-cli/ for troubleshooting.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

For any further commands, please switch to the ghost-mgr user to manage Ghost.

    sudo -i -u ghost-mgr

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of searching and it appears from this thread that you need to set up an SSL at the other end rather than using the one from Netlify:
https://community.netlify.com/t/how-to-do-dns-ssl-for-sub-domain-that-doesnt-run-on-netlify/5498/11

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into this once I get some time.